# UICollectionView scrolling

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uicollectionview

I have UICollectionView. If I scroll it to the end of its last section it is always at the bottom. 
I need a header at the last section under the navigation bar. How to do it? I use following code to place the header behind navigation bar.

```
- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity {

    if (velocity.y == 0) {

    } else {

    NSArray *array =
    [super layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:({
        CGRect bounds = self.collectionView.bounds;
        bounds.origin.y = proposedContentOffset.y - self.collectionView.bounds.size.height/2.f;
        bounds.size.width *= 1.5f;
        bounds;
    })];

    CGFloat minOffsetY = CGFLOAT_MAX;
    UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *targetLayoutAttributes = nil;

    for (UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *layoutAttributes in array) {
        if ([layoutAttributes.representedElementKind isEqualToString:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader]) {
            CGFloat offsetY = fabs(layoutAttributes.frame.origin.y - proposedContentOffset.y);

            if (offsetY < minOffsetY) {
                minOffsetY = offsetY;

                CGPoint origin = layoutAttributes.frame.origin;
                origin.y = origin.y+28;
                layoutAttributes.frame = (CGRect){
                .origin = origin,
                .size = layoutAttributes.frame.size
                };

                targetLayoutAttributes = layoutAttributes;
            }
        }
    }

    if (targetLayoutAttributes) {
        return targetLayoutAttributes.frame.origin;
    }
    }
   return CGPointMake(proposedContentOffset.x, proposedContentOffset.y);
}
```

And if the there is only one section I also have the same problem.